# R.string not compiling

Tags: android

If R.string.start is referring to the strings.xml file then why does it give me the error "start cannot be resolved or is not a field" error? Shouldn't it see this `<string name="start">Starting...</string>`inside the strings.xml file and compile correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, HandlerUpdateUi!</string>
<string name="app_name">HandlerUpdateUi</string>
<string name="action">Press to Start</string>
<string name="start">Starting...</string>
<string name="first">First Done</string>
<string name="second">Second Done</string>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView av; //UI reference
    int textString = R.string.start;
    int backgroundColor = Color.DKGRAY;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // Create runnable for posting results to the UI thread
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            av.setText(textString);
            av.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        }
    };@
    Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            av = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.computation_status);
            Button actionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action1);
            actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    doWork();
                }
            });
        }
        //example of a computationally intensive action with UI updates
    private void doWork() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textString = R.id.start;
                backgroundColor = Color.DKGRAY;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                computation(1);
                textString = R.id.first;

                backgroundColor = Color.BLUE;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                computation(2);
                textString = R.id.second;
                backgroundColor = Color.GREEN;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    final static int SIZE = 1000; //large enough to take some time
    double tmp;
    private void computation(int val) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < SIZE; ii++)
            for (int jj = 0; jj < SIZE; jj++)
                tmp = val * Math.log(ii + 1) / Math.log1p(jj + 1);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

New to Android?

You need to import R.

**R.java** is a generated file with all the stuff you declare in the XML's, and you need to import it just like any other file.

The location is your project **package name**, so if your package name is **com.mycoolproject**, you need to do:

```
import com.mycoolproject.R;
```

And then you can reference layouts, resources, drawables, etc... from your project.

When you write more complex programs, sometimes you'll need different **R**'s. For example, you could need to use something declared in android's R, which holds the default android resources, like some animations and default styles. In this case, you'd reference such things like this:

```
android.R.anim.push_in
```

Also, if you include library projects, each library project would have its own **R**.